# Showing a Graph using KIVY as part of a Box Layout

Tags: python, kivy

I am new to using Kivy.  What I want to do is insert a graph as part of a box layout.  I am getting the following error message:  AttributeError: 'kivy.properties.DictProperty' object has no attribute 'destination'

I'm sure the solution is simple but I can't seem to get there. Any help would be great.

## Python Code:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.9.0')

from kivy.garden.matplotlib.backend_kivyagg import FigureCanvasKivyAgg
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


plt.plot([1, 23, 2, 4])
plt.ylabel('some numbers')

class BoxLayoutApp(App):

    def build(self):
        box = BoxLayout()
        BoxLayout.ids.destination.add_widget(FigureCanvasKivyAgg(plt.gcf()))
        return box

blApp = BoxLayoutApp()
blApp.run()
```

Kivy Code========================================================================

```
<BoxLayout>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    spacing: 10
    padding: 10
    canvas.before:
        Rectangle:
            id: destination
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    Button:
        text: "2nd"     
    Button:
        text: "3rd"
```

Comment: The `ids` dictionary is not filled out in the `build()` method. Try calling that statement via a `Clock.schedule_once()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I don't think the `ids` dictionary is your problem. It looks like you are trying to add the `FigureCanvasKivyAgg` to a `Rectangle` canvas instruction. You should just add it to your `BoxLayout` as shown below:

```
import kivy
from kivy.lang import Builder

kivy.require('1.9.0')

from kivy.garden.matplotlib.backend_kivyagg import FigureCanvasKivyAgg
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Builder.load_string('''
<BoxLayout>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    spacing: 10
    padding: 10
    Button:
        text: "2nd"     
    Button:
        text: "3rd"
''')

plt.plot([1, 23, 2, 4])
plt.ylabel('some numbers')

class BoxLayoutApp(App):

    def build(self):
        box = BoxLayout()
        box.add_widget(FigureCanvasKivyAgg(plt.gcf()))
        return box

blApp = BoxLayoutApp()
blApp.run()
```

Comment: Thanks.   I was hoping to get more clarity on the *ids* functionality.   I am building an app and need to place graphs inside of a tabbed panel.   I you know of any docs that address this issue please let me know.

Comment: I am struggling to add the graph the tabbed panel.   I can make the graph run and display outside my Kivy app by using plt.show(),  I can add images into the panel, I can add another BoxLayout into the pannel but run into issues at every approach I take.

Comment: The `ids` are not immediately available in a `build` or `__init__` method. Typically, you would need to access the `ids` either through a `Clock.schedule_once` call, or through any GUI action (like a button press). The `ids` are placed in a dictionary of the root object of the `kv` block. Also, you would access your `ids` through the `box` instance, not the `BoxLayout` class.

Comment: The `ids` are documented [here](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/lang.html#referencing-widgets). You can also use `ObjectProperty` to reference objects from your `kv` file as documented [here](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/lang.html#accessing-widgets-defined-inside-kv-lang-in-your-python-code).